# How to open a new jsf window in bean?

Tags: jsf, netbeans, facelets

I am totally new about jsf page.

I want build a log in page, where you write in the correct password you will get to a new page, and if not it will show "invalid password". 
now I can already validate if the password the correct using "if else" in the bean part. i figure if I can just direct to the next window it would be fine but I just cant get that part done... help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<h:commandButton action="page2" value="Page2" />
```

where page2 is the name of the page you want to show.

See also: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_page_navigation.htm

then do this:

```
<h:commandButton action="{YourBean.validateUser()}" />
```

In the bean:

```
public String validateUser() {
// Validate the user...
if (theUserIsValid) {
    return "page2"
} else { 
    return null;
}
```

Where page2 is the name of the page you want to show when the user is validated.

Comment: The problem is, I need the password to be correct to log in. if I write action "page2" on the command button, wouldn't even the wrong password be able to log in?